# How to send email alerts at scale using Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, server, nodemailer

I am building a program where the user can select a crypto currency, enter their email and basically it will remind them with an email when the crypto hits the user's selected price. (A price notifier by email). I have got email working and a crypto api to get the price data, but now i am just wondering how i am going to get the program to save the users data and every time i get the price data how am i going to send email to multiple users who have signed up for reminders. I hope this is making sense, i will post relevant code below.

Getting price data

```
async function getPriceData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin",
      {}
    );

    const data = response.data;
    const price = data.market_data.current_price.usd;

    return price;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Email function that uses price data to send email. (Currently using setTimeout to keep checking price data but im not sure this is the best way to keep checking api).
I am using nodemailer for sending emails and all working fine.

Client data is posted to server and used in this function, all working fine.

```
const emailFunction = (price, recieverEmail) => {
  getPriceData().then((response) => {
    const btcPrice = response;
    const selectedPrice = price;

    if (btcPrice < selectedPrice) {
      const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
        port: 587,
        auth: {
          user: "apikey",
          pass: sendgridKey,
        },
      });

      const message = {
        from: senderEmail,
        to: recieverEmail,
        subject: `BTC PRICE BELOW ${selectedPrice}!`,
        text: `Bitcoin price is below your selected price of ${selectedPrice}, and is currently ${btcPrice}. This presents a good buying opportunity.`,
      };

      transport.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(info);
        }
      });
    }

    setTimeout(emailFunction, 60000);
  });
};
```

Currently i can only send emails for one user and i use the setTimeout to check the api to get price data every 60000ms. This works for now but the end product i would like the user to input email and price and the back end will continuously check api and if coin price has gone below the users price, the user will be alerted at that point. How does this scale to keep track of price and say email 50 people if needed?

Thanks for any input and help on this, much appreciated i am a Node noob.

Comment: *how i am going to get the program to save the users data* - traditionally, this is what a *database* is used for - it doesn't have to be anything too complex for 50 people - simply store info in a file stored on the server

Comment: I have set up Amazon Simple Email Service. It is quite cheap and, mainly because you have to verify your domain name or email address with Amazon, your emails are considered more trustworthy (so long as you don't send loads of spam and emails to non existant addresses) and hence are less likely to go into recipients' spam folders. You can send emails programmatically using SES.

Comment: @JaromandaX so would learning Mongo db be useful or literally just store the info in a file and look at that file every time i get price data? Thanks for your help.

Comment: up to you - for 50 users I wouldn't bother with anything more than a file - and you wouldn't need to read it every time you get price data, the file is just to store user info persistently so that if your code needs to restart it doesn't lose all the user data